# High CRP levels

Tags: inflammation, crp-c-reactive-protein

What happens if you consistently have high CRP levels from inflammation, but, even after multiple examinations in the hospital the underlying cause for the high CRP levels cannot be found?

Does this mean there is no inflammation to begin with and the CRP levels are just high for some other reason? Or is it the doctors could not test every possible possibility?

By this logic, if CRP levels are consistently high especially in elderly and underlying cause cannot be identified, eventually they will die from the complications to high CRP ( as clearly something is not right in the body).

So what is the usual medical actions taken by doctors in cases like these?

Comment: CRP is such a broadly encountered marker that I haven't heard of a flowchart for differential diagnosis other than "see what else the patient complains about or what else shows up abnormal in tests."

Comment: [FWTW](https://pulmonarychronicles.com/index.php/pulmonarychronicles/article/view/501/1085) "Patients with high CRP but normal ESR typically have infection, ischemia, or thromboembolism." But it cites a single study for that; also notes in conclusion that CRP by itself is not useful in establishing a diagnosis.